# regex match a word not inside [ and ]

Tags: php, regex

I would like to replace all words (such as *test*) not inside [ and ] by *[test]* in PHP using the function `preg_replace`.

I've done this right now :

```
$txt = preg_replace('#([^\[])' . $word . '([^\]])#i', '[' . $word . ']', $txt);
```

but the pattern does not match test

here is my test :

```
$txt = 'atesta, test, [test], [atesta]';
$pattern = '#(?:^|[^\[])test(?:[^\]]|$)#i';
$replace = '[test]';
echo "$txt<br />";
$txt = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $txt);
echo "$txt<br />";
$txt = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $txt);
echo "$txt<br />";
```

Comment: Note that the way it is written now, the word _must_ be preceded and followed by a single character: words at the beginning or at the end of a line will not match.

Comment: Note that you don't need to escape the square brackets here. `[^[]` is ok because `[` has no meaning inside a class, and `[^]]` is ok because a class must contain at least one character, so `[^]` alone would be invalid, resulting in `]` having no special meaning (similar to how `-` at the start or end of a class has no meaning)

Comment: What do you want as result for each of your test strings. And what about `atesta` without brackets?

Comment: just updated my post, atesta fails

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$txt = preg_replace('#(?:^|[^\[])'.$word.'(?:[^\]]|$)#i', '['.$word.']', $txt);
```

Comment: hi, this works partially, because it works if for [test] but I would like it to work for [test1, test2]

Comment: @Bouki:Please update your question with as much as possible test cases.

Comment: just updated my post, the fact is that i can have [atesta] (test is not immediatly inside [ and ] but there can be something before and after)